# Can't receive WM_MOUSEWHEEL event in npapi windowless plugin

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin

I've written a windowless NPAPI plugin and I want to handle mouse events in NPP_HandleEvent().

I can get WM_PAINT, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, and WM_MOUSEMOVE event without any problem.

However, it's wired that I can't receive any WM_MOUSEWHEEL event.

```
uint16_t CWinLessPlugin::HandleEvent(void *event)
{
    NPEvent *pevent = (NPEvent *) event;

    switch (pevent->event)
    {   
    case WM_PAINT:
         break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
         HandleIt();
         break;
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
         //never 
         break;
    }
    return 1;
 }
```

I really can't figure out why :(.  Any help will be very appreciated.

chrome version : 31.0.1650.63

firefox version : 25.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WM_MOUSEWHEEL` is not included in the list of (supported) events in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPEvent#Fields). Firefox definitely doesn't support it [[1]](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/118234ab24ed/dom/plugins/ipc/NPEventWindows.h#l63) [[2]](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/118234ab24ed/dom/plugins/base/nsPluginInstanceOwner.cpp#l1917), Chrome probably doesn't either.

Answer (score 0):

I reported that as a bug in firefox, let's see if mouse wheel event will be supported in a browser post 2014.

link:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1057972